# How to Render a State Abbreviation in Craft CMS?

Tags: templating

Folks,

Is there a way to render a state abbreviation in a front end template on Craft CMS? Currently, I have a plain text field that has the full text of a state and I would like to render the standard two letter abbreviation.

Here is my current code:

```
{% if eventType.eventState | length %}{{ eventType.eventState }}{% endif %}
```

I would be open to changing the field type (or downloading a plugin) if that makes things easier but don't see an address field or something that on the surface would be conducive to easily filtering down to an abbreviation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's anything native (and haven't seen a plugin) that does this, but one way to do it is to create a [macro](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html) where you add all the states and their abbreviations to a map. Something like this should work:

In a file called `templates/_macros/helpers.html` or the like (abbreviations map shortened in example; you can find a full list [here](https://gist.github.com/jimkutter/1370525), just need to convert it to Twig object syntax):

```
{% macro abbreviateState(stateName) %}{% spaceless %}

    {% set abbreviations = {
        'Alabama': 'AL',
        'Alaska': 'AK',
        'Arizona': 'AZ',
        'Arkansas': 'AR',
        'California': 'CA',
        'Colorado': 'CO',
        'Connecticut': 'CT',
        ...
    } %}

    {{ abbreviations[stateName|trim] ?? stateName }}

{% endspaceless %}{% endmacro %}
```

In your template (i.e. /templates/entry.html):

```
{# Import macro at the top of the template #}
{% import '_macros/helpers' as helpers %}

{% if eventType.eventState | length %}

    {{ helpers.abbreviateState(eventType.eventState) }}

{% endif %}
```

Of course, this solution hinges on the state names being typed properly (exactly the same way as they appear in the macro); if somebody were to write "New york" and you've got "New York" in the macro, a proper abbreviation would not be found and the state name "New york" would simply render as-is.

To mitigate this, you might consider opting for a different input field type other than Plain Text, e.g. a Dropdown where you set up all the states as options.

If you're sticking with a Plain Text field, you could also circumvent the specific issue of capitalisation being off by making the state names in the macro map all lowercase, and applying the `|lower` filter to the state name when you try to pull the abbreviation:

```
{% set abbreviations = {
    'alabama': 'AL',
    'alaska': 'AK',
    'arizona': 'AZ',
    'arkansas': 'AR',
    'california': 'CA',
    'colorado': 'CO',
    'connecticut': 'CT',
    ...
} %}

{{ abbreviations[stateName|trim|lower] ?? stateName }}
```

Comment: This is a great idea / approach! Ultimately, would be great to see this as a native feature in Craft, possibly via an address field with a filter of some sort, but in the meantime this is great. Thank you!